# Custom NavigationLink SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a custom NavigationLink in SwiftUI. Now I'm trying to add `isActive` to my customNavLink but I'm facing with `Missing argument for parameter 'isActive' in call`  across all project. I want to make this isActive `optional` to use where I need it.

Do you know how could I resolve this issue?

This is My CustomNavLink

```
struct CusNavLink<Label: View, Destination: View>: View {

    let destination: Destination
    let label : Label
    let isActive: Binding<Bool>

    init(destination: Destination, isActive: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) {
        self.destination = destination
        self.label = label()
        self.isActive = isActive
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: CusNavContainer{
                destination
            }
                .navigationBarHidden(true),
            isActive: isActive,
            label:{
                label
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `isActive` to be `Optional`, you'd have to declare it as such in the initializer and properties. Then, you'd conditionally display a different `NavigationLink` initializer depending on if you have an `isActive` `Binding` to pass it:

```
struct CusNavLink<Label: View, Destination: View>: View {

    let destination: Destination
    let label : Label
    let isActive: Binding<Bool>?

    init(destination: Destination, isActive: Binding<Bool>? = nil, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) {
        self.destination = destination
        self.label = label()
        self.isActive = isActive
    }

    var body: some View {
        if let isActive = isActive {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: CusNavContainer {
                    destination
                }
                .navigationBarHidden(true),
                isActive: isActive,
                label:{
                    label
                })
        } else {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: CusNavContainer {
                    destination
                }
                .navigationBarHidden(true),
                label:{
                    label
                })
        }
    }
}
```